# Regular Expression - replace word except within a URL/URI

Tags: ruby, regex, url, replace, cpu-word

Writing a globalization module for a web application and I need a regexp to replace all instances of a word with another word (the translation) - except - words found within a URL/URI.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that I'm using Ruby, so I can't use 'Lookbehind'

Comment: Doing translation by word replacement is doomed to failure.

Comment: Ive tried using this:
    '/((?<=>|^)[^<]*)(\bfoo\b)([^<]*(?=<|$))/i'
But it requires Lookbehind, which Ruby doesn't support

Comment: Ruby 1.9 supports lookbehind.  Are you using 1.8?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- Split on URI regular expression; include the URI's in the result.
- For each piece:

  - if it is a URI, leave it alone
  - otherwise, do word replacement
- Join the pieces

Code:

```
# From RFC 3986 Appendix B, with these modifications:
#   o Spaces disallowed
#   o All groups non-matching, except for added outermost group
#   o Not anchored
#   o Scheme required
#   o Authority required
URI_REGEX = %r"((?:(?:[^ :/?#]+):)(?://(?:[^ /?#]*))(?:[^ ?#]*)(?:\?(?:[^ #]*))?(?:#(?:[^ ]*))?)"

def replace_except_uris(text, old, new)
  text.split(URI_REGEX).collect do |s|
    if s =~ URI_REGEX
      s
    else
      s.gsub(old, new)
    end
  end.join
end

text = <<END
stack http://www.stackoverflow.com stack
stack http://www.somewhere.come/stack?stack=stack#stack stack
END

puts replace_except_uris(text, /stack/, 'LINKED-LIST')

# => LINKED-LIST http://www.stackoverflow.com LINKED-LIST
# => LINKED-LIST http://www.somewhere.come/stack?stack=stack#stack LINKED-LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

You can probaby use something like

```
(?<!://[^ ]*)\bfoo\b
```

But this probably isn't perfect, it just looks that the word doesn't appear in a single non-whitespace string of characters that don't have `://` somewhere before the word.

```
PS Home:\> "foo foobar http://foo_bar/baz?gak=foobar baz foo" -replace '(?<!://[^ ]*)\bfoo\b', 'FOO'
FOO foobar http://foo_bar/baz?gak=foobar baz FOO
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried splitting your text into words and iterating over the words?  Then you can examine each word, determine if it's a URI, translate it if it isn't.