# Removing url from text using ruby

Tags: ruby, regex, text, substitution

Given a text, I want to remove the url part and leave other text.

Example:

```
'bla bla bla... bla bla bla... http://bit.ly/someuri bla bla bla...'
```

to become

```
'bla bla bla... bla bla bla... bla bla bla...'
```

Is there any ruby build in method to do this efficiently?

Comment: Can you guarantee there won't be any spaces within the url?

Comment: The text is entered by user, so my main concern is just remove anything that resembles a url up to the next space. `'http://bit.ly/the url with space'` will become `'url with space'`

Answer (score 9):

Try with regex:

```
(?:f|ht)tps?:\/[^\s]+
```

Comment: @Donny Kurnia lets say you have your string in a variable `str`, then you can use @The Mask's regex like so : `new_str = str.gsub(/(?:f|ht)tps?:\/[^\s]+/, '')` or if you want `str` itself to change you can do `str.gsub!(/(?:f|ht)tps?:\/[^\s]+/, '')`

Comment: @DhruvaSagar the answer above worked where mine failed. @inbound_text.gsub!(/<http:(.*)>/m, ''). Why? Nice answer.

Answer (score 4):

I just found [Regular Expression - replace word except within a URL/URI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162860/regular-expression-replace-word-except-within-a-url-uri) and modify the code to be like this:

```
URI_REGEX = %r"((?:(?:[^ :/?#]+):)(?://(?:[^ /?#]*))(?:[^ ?#]*)(?:\?(?:[^ #]*))?(?:#(?:[^ ]*))?)"

def remove_uris(text)
  text.split(URI_REGEX).collect do |s|
    unless s =~ URI_REGEX
      s
    end
  end.join
end
```

I test it in rails console and it worked as expected:

```
remove_uris('bla bla bla... bla bla bla... http://bit.ly/someuri bla bla bla...')
=> "bla bla bla... bla bla bla...  bla bla bla..."
```

If anyone have better / effective solution, I will vote up or accept it. Thanks.

Comment: what about text.gsub!(URI_REGEX, '') ?

Comment: Please note that this doesn't work 100%. Consider the following text: `"تفاصيل تغطية\n#lexusriyadhlargestglobally\n#لكزس_الرياض_الأكبر_في_العالم\nتجدونها هنا\nhttp://example.com\n http://example.com"` some parts of the arabic text and emojis are left out